# Show that $(S,\ast)$ is commutative if and only if $(T,\Box)$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $(S,\ast)$ and $(T,\Box)$ are isomorphic binary structures.

> Show that $(S,\ast)$ is commutative if and only if $(T,\Box)$ is commutative.

Since $(S,\ast) \cong (T,\Box)$, we have $f(a \ast b) = f(a) \Box f(b)$.

I know I need to show that $a \ast b = b \ast a$ for all $a,b \in S \Longleftrightarrow a \Box b = b \Box a$ for all $a,b \in T$ but I am having trouble showing that the commutativity of $(S,\ast)$ implies that $(T,\Box)$ is also commutative. If I could get some help on one direction ($a \ast b = b \ast a$ for all $a,b \in S \Rightarrow a \Box b = b \Box a$ for all $a,b \in T$) then I could probably figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Suppose $(S, \ast)$ is commutative and take arbitrary $a, b \in T$. Since $f: S \to T$ is an isomorphism and in particular a bijection, $a$ and $b$ have unique preimages in $S$, and by hypothesis these commute:
$$f^{-1}(a) \ast f^{-1}(b) = f^{-1}(b) \ast f^{-1}(a).$$
Now, apply $f$ to both sides.

> Using that $f$ is an isomorphism (of the binary structure) gives precisely that $a, b$ commute. Since $a, b \in T$ are arbitrary, $(T, \square)$ is commutative.

Comment: Does this work? $f^{-1}(a\Box b) = f^{-1}(a) \ast f^{-1}(b) = f^{-1}(b) \ast f^{-1}(a) = f^{-1}(b \Box a)$. Since $f^{-1}(a\Box b) = f^{-1}(b \Box a)$, applying $f$ to both sides yields $a \Box b = b \Box a$

Comment: Yes, it does, and NB the first and third equalities use the fact that if $f$ is an isomorphism then so is $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I posted a detailed answer and some feedback would be great.

Comment: You're welcome. With egreg's suggested modification, your solution looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Indeed any isomorphism $f$ has to satisfy $f(a*b) = f(a)\square f(b)$. However, isomorphisms are much stronger, in particular it has to be a bijection and $f^{-1}(a\square b) = f^{-1}(a)*f^{-1}(b)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I will try the problem again.

Comment: Does this work? $f^{-1}(a\Box b) = f^{-1}(a) \ast f^{-1}(b) = f^{-1}(b) \ast f^{-1}(a) = f^{-1}(b \Box a)$. Since $f^{-1}(a\Box b) = f^{-1}(b \Box a)$, applying $f$ to both sides yields $a \Box b = b \Box a$

Comment: @StVincent Yes, that does work. If you wish, you could put that all into one equation, namely $$a\square b = f\big(f^{-1}(a\Box b)\big) = f\big(f^{-1}(a) * f^{-1}(b)\big) = f\big(f^{-1}(b) \ast f^{-1}(a)\big) = f\big(f^{-1}(b \Box a)\big) = b\square a,$$ but I like your solution more.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I like your solution too! I posted a detailed answer, and some feedback would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $(S,\ast)$ is commutative and take $a,b \in T$. Since $f:(S,\ast) \to (T,\Box)$ is an isomorphism, it follows that $f^{-1}:(T,\Box) \to (S,\ast)$ is also. Thus  $$\begin{align} f^{-1}(a \Box b) &= f^{-1}(a)\ast f^{-1}(b) \\&= f^{-1}(b) \ast f^{-1}(a) \\&= f^{-1}(b \Box a).\end{align}$$
Applying $f$ to both sides of $f^{-1}(a \Box b) = f^{-1}(b \Box a)$ yields $a \Box b = b \Box a$, demonstrating that $(T,\Box)$ is commutative.

Now assume that $(T,\Box)$ is commutative and let $a,b \in S$. Since $f$ is an isomorphism, we have $$\begin{align} f(a \ast b) &= f(a) \Box f(b) \\&=f(b) \Box f(a) \\&=f(b \ast a).\end{align}$$

We may apply the inverse $f^{-1}$ to both sides to obtain $a \ast b = b \ast a$, demonstrating that $(S, \ast)$ is commutative, as desired. $\Box$

Comment: You don't need to prove the converse, once you observe that $f^{-1}\colon T\to S$ is an isomorphism, because you have proved the direct statement *for every isomorphism*.

Comment: Should I just omit the paragraph starting with "Now assume that $(T, \Box)$ is commutative and let..."?

Comment: “The converse is proved by considering the isomorphism $f^{-1}$.”

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies it.